# Is there any way to access the stack trace of an exception thrown by {}.InvokeWithContext()?

Tags: powershell, exception, stack-trace

Consider the following:

```
function d { e }
function e { throw 'exception in e' }
function f { { g }.InvokeWithContext(@{},$null) }
function g { throw 'exception in g' }

Describe 'stack trace' {
    It 'normal' { d }
    It '.InvokeWithContext()' { f }
}
```

Pester usually does a pretty good job at displaying stack traces.  In the second test case, however, the stack trace starts with `.InvokeWithContext()` instead of `throw 'exception in g'`:

```
Describing stack trace
 [-] normal 61ms
   RuntimeException: exception in e
   at e, <No file>: line 2
   at d, <No file>: line 1
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 7
 [-] .InvokeWithContext() 85ms
   RuntimeException: exception in g
   RuntimeException: exception in g
   MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" 
with "2" argument(s): "exception in g"
   at f, <No file>: line 3
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 8
```

`throw 'exception in g'` is where the exception really originated but that is missing from the stack trace.  I've caught the exception and examined it before Pester gets it, but I haven't been able to find the missing bits of stack trace in the exception object myself.

1. Is there a way to access the stack trace of an exception thrown by `.InvokeWithContext()`?
2. Is there some other way to invoke a script block in the context of functions and variables similar to `InvokeWithContext()`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an automatic variable **$StackTrace** (more specific to internal PS details than actual). Not that much helpful.

There is a **Get-PSCallStack** but that will be off as soon as you hit exception.

You can put a **Get-PSCallStack** before every throw in your script. 
That way you get a stack trace immediately before hitting an exception.

Apart from these: there is a function which I have taken from StackOverflow earlier.

```
Function Resolve-Error
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Enumerate error record details.

.DESCRIPTION
    Enumerate an error record, or a collection of error record, properties. By default, the details
    for the last error will be enumerated.

.PARAMETER ErrorRecord
    The error record to resolve. The default error record is the lastest one: $global:Error[0].
    This parameter will also accept an array of error records.

.PARAMETER Property
    The list of properties to display from the error record. Use "*" to display all properties.
    Default list of error properties is: Message, FullyQualifiedErrorId, ScriptStackTrace, PositionMessage, InnerException

    Below is a list of all of the possible available properties on the error record:

    Error Record:               Error Invocation:           Error Exception:                    Error Inner Exception(s):
    $_                          $_.InvocationInfo           $_.Exception                        $_.Exception.InnerException
    -------------               -----------------           ----------------                    ---------------------------
    writeErrorStream            MyCommand                   ErrorRecord                         Data
    PSMessageDetails            BoundParameters             ItemName                            HelpLink
    Exception                   UnboundArguments            SessionStateCategory                HResult
    TargetObject                ScriptLineNumber            StackTrace                          InnerException
    CategoryInfo                OffsetInLine                WasThrownFromThrowStatement         Message
    FullyQualifiedErrorId       HistoryId                   Message                             Source
    ErrorDetails                ScriptName                  Data                                StackTrace
    InvocationInfo              Line                        InnerException                      TargetSite
    ScriptStackTrace            PositionMessage             TargetSite                          
    PipelineIterationInfo       PSScriptRoot                HelpLink                            
                                PSCommandPath               Source                              
                                InvocationName              HResult                             
                                PipelineLength              
                                PipelinePosition            
                                ExpectingInput              
                                CommandOrigin               
                                DisplayScriptPosition       

.PARAMETER GetErrorRecord
    Get error record details as represented by $_
    Default is to display details. To skip details, specify -GetErrorRecord:$false

.PARAMETER GetErrorInvocation
    Get error record invocation information as represented by $_.InvocationInfo
    Default is to display details. To skip details, specify -GetErrorInvocation:$false

.PARAMETER GetErrorException
    Get error record exception details as represented by $_.Exception
    Default is to display details. To skip details, specify -GetErrorException:$false

.PARAMETER GetErrorInnerException
    Get error record inner exception details as represented by $_.Exception.InnerException.
    Will retrieve all inner exceptions if there is more then one.
    Default is to display details. To skip details, specify -GetErrorInnerException:$false

.EXAMPLE
    Resolve-Error

    Get the default error details for the last error

.EXAMPLE
    Resolve-Error -ErrorRecord $global:Error[0,1]

    Get the default error details for the last two errors

.EXAMPLE
    Resolve-Error -Property *

    Get all of the error details for the last error

.EXAMPLE
    Resolve-Error -Property InnerException

    Get the "InnerException" for the last error

.EXAMPLE
    Resolve-Error -GetErrorInvocation:$false

    Get the default error details for the last error but exclude the error invocation information

.NOTES
.LINK
#>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [array]$ErrorRecord,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [string[]]$Property = ('Message','InnerException','FullyQualifiedErrorId','ScriptStackTrace','PositionMessage'),

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [switch]$GetErrorRecord = $true,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
        [switch]$GetErrorInvocation = $true,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
        [switch]$GetErrorException = $true,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=5)]
        [switch]$GetErrorInnerException = $true
    )

    Begin
    {
        ## If function was called without specifying an error record, then choose the latest error that occured
        If (-not $ErrorRecord)
        {
            If ($global:Error.Count -eq 0)
            {
                # The `$Error collection is empty
                Return
            }
            Else
            {
                [array]$ErrorRecord = $global:Error[0]
            }
        }

        ## Define script block for selecting and filtering the properties on the error object
        [scriptblock]$SelectProperty = {
            Param
            (
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
                $InputObject,

                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
                [string[]]$Property
            )
            [string[]]$ObjectProperty = $InputObject | Get-Member -MemberType *Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
            ForEach ($Prop in $Property)
            {
                If ($Prop -eq '*')
                {
                    [string[]]$PropertySelection = $ObjectProperty
                    Break
                }
                ElseIf ($ObjectProperty -contains $Prop)
                {
                    [string[]]$PropertySelection += $Prop
                }
            }
            Write-Output $PropertySelection
        }

        # Initialize variables to avoid error if 'Set-StrictMode' is set
        $LogErrorRecordMsg      = $null
        $LogErrorInvocationMsg  = $null
        $LogErrorExceptionMsg   = $null
        $LogErrorMessageTmp     = $null
        $LogInnerMessage        = $null
    }
    Process
    {
        ForEach ($ErrRecord in $ErrorRecord)
        {
            ## Capture Error Record
            If ($GetErrorRecord)
            {
                [string[]]$SelectedProperties = &$SelectProperty -InputObject $ErrRecord -Property $Property
                $LogErrorRecordMsg = $ErrRecord | Select-Object -Property $SelectedProperties
            }

            ## Error Invocation Information
            If ($GetErrorInvocation)
            {
                If ($ErrRecord.InvocationInfo)
                {
                    [string[]]$SelectedProperties = &$SelectProperty -InputObject $ErrRecord.InvocationInfo -Property $Property
                    $LogErrorInvocationMsg = $ErrRecord.InvocationInfo | Select-Object -Property $SelectedProperties
                }
            }

            ## Capture Error Exception
            If ($GetErrorException)
            {
                If ($ErrRecord.Exception)
                {
                    [string[]]$SelectedProperties = &$SelectProperty -InputObject $ErrRecord.Exception -Property $Property
                    $LogErrorExceptionMsg = $ErrRecord.Exception | Select-Object -Property $SelectedProperties
                }
            }

            ## Display properties in the correct order
            If ($Property -eq '*')
            {
                # If all properties were chosen for display, then arrange them in the order
                #  the error object displays them by default.
                If ($LogErrorRecordMsg)     {[array]$LogErrorMessageTmp += $LogErrorRecordMsg    }
                If ($LogErrorInvocationMsg) {[array]$LogErrorMessageTmp += $LogErrorInvocationMsg}
                If ($LogErrorExceptionMsg)  {[array]$LogErrorMessageTmp += $LogErrorExceptionMsg }
            }
            Else
            {
                # Display selected properties in our custom order
                If ($LogErrorExceptionMsg)  {[array]$LogErrorMessageTmp += $LogErrorExceptionMsg }
                If ($LogErrorRecordMsg)     {[array]$LogErrorMessageTmp += $LogErrorRecordMsg    }
                If ($LogErrorInvocationMsg) {[array]$LogErrorMessageTmp += $LogErrorInvocationMsg}
            }

            If ($LogErrorMessageTmp)
            {
                $LogErrorMessage  = 'Error Record:'
                $LogErrorMessage += "`n-------------"
                $LogErrorMsg      = $LogErrorMessageTmp | Format-List | Out-String
                $LogErrorMessage += $LogErrorMsg
            }

            ## Capture Error Inner Exception(s)
            If ($GetErrorInnerException)
            {
                If ($ErrRecord.Exception -and $ErrRecord.Exception.InnerException)
                {
                    $LogInnerMessage  = 'Error Inner Exception(s):'
                    $LogInnerMessage += "`n-------------------------"

                    $ErrorInnerException = $ErrRecord.Exception.InnerException
                    $Count = 0

                    While ($ErrorInnerException)
                    {
                        $InnerExceptionSeperator = '~' * 40

                        [string[]]$SelectedProperties = &$SelectProperty -InputObject $ErrorInnerException -Property $Property
                        $LogErrorInnerExceptionMsg = $ErrorInnerException | Select-Object -Property $SelectedProperties | Format-List | Out-String

                        If ($Count -gt 0)
                        {
                            $LogInnerMessage += $InnerExceptionSeperator
                        }
                        $LogInnerMessage += $LogErrorInnerExceptionMsg

                        $Count++
                        $ErrorInnerException = $ErrorInnerException.InnerException
                    }
                }
            }

            If ($LogErrorMessage) { $Output += $LogErrorMessage }
            If ($LogInnerMessage) { $Output += $LogInnerMessage }

            Write-Output $Output

            If (Test-Path -Path 'variable:Output'            ) { Clear-Variable -Name Output             }
            If (Test-Path -Path 'variable:LogErrorMessage'   ) { Clear-Variable -Name LogErrorMessage    }
            If (Test-Path -Path 'variable:LogInnerMessage'   ) { Clear-Variable -Name LogInnerMessage    }
            If (Test-Path -Path 'variable:LogErrorMessageTmp') { Clear-Variable -Name LogErrorMessageTmp }
        }
    }
    End {}
}
```

**Usage:**

```
"Failed : `n$(Resolve-Error)"
```

This is the original source code link : [Github Link](https://github.com/alx9r/ZeroDSC/issues/36#issue-201880073)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm...I don't think embedding `Get-PSCallStack` in the offending code will help.  I'm just using `throw` in the example to cause an exception.  In the real project where I am running into the problem, I can't predict what is going to throw the exception.

Comment: Hi, please include the original source of the code you are using

Comment: @sodawillow The full repro is [this github issue](https://github.com/alx9r/ZeroDSC/issues/36#issue-201880073).

Comment: It looks like `Resolve-Error` is looking at `$global:Error[0]` to produce its output.  (I didn't know that variable existed until now).  Unfortunately, `$global:Error[0].ScriptStackTrace` omits the originating lines in exactly the same way as the `.ScriptStackTrace` property of the exception that `.InvokeWithContext()` raises.